# Android App crashes with DeadObjectException

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using coroutines to send the network request and my app crashes whenever I turn on the airplane mode. It works absolutely fine when having airplane mode turned off.

Following is the viewmodel class:

```
package com.example.retrofitsample.ViewModel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.retrofitsample.Network.CountryListRepository
import com.example.retrofitsample.Model.Country
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow

class CountryListViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val repository: CountryListRepository by lazy {
    CountryListRepository()
}

private val _errorMsg = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
val errorMsg: StateFlow<String?> = _errorMsg.asStateFlow()

private val _countryList = MutableStateFlow<List<Country>>(emptyList())
val countryList = _countryList.asStateFlow()

private val _loading = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
val loading = _loading.asStateFlow()

fun getAllCountries() {
    if (_countryList.value.isEmpty().not() || _loading.value) return

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            _loading.value = true
        }
        val response = repository.getAllCountries()
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { _countryList.value = it }
            _loading.value = false
        } else {
            onError("Error : ${response.message()} ")
        }

    }
}

private fun onError(message: String) {
    _errorMsg.value = message
    _loading.value = false
}
```

}

I added a log after `val response = repository.getAllCountries()` line and it never gets printed.

Getting the following exception:

```
> 03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{184054c u0 com.example.retrofitsample/com.example.retrofitsample.UI.MainActivity EXITING}
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:473)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3994)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$5$com-android-server-wm-InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:348)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:2)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:345)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace(RootWindowContainer.java:840)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement(RootWindowContainer.java:784)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:177)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:126)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:115)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer$Traverser.run(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:57)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
03-14 19:49:16.503   572   595 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
03-14 19:49:16.513   409   505 W TransactionTracing: Could not find layer handle 0xb400007504b20c90
03-14 19:49:16.516   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.533   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.549   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.566   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.584   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.599   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.615   387   482 W RanchuHwc: presentDisplay display has no layers to compose, flushing client target buffer.
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager: Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{184054c u0 com.example.retrofitsample/com.example.retrofitsample.UI.MainActivity EXITING}
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchAppVisibility(IWindow.java:536)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowState.java:3489)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowContainer.java:1199)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible(WindowToken.java:398)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible(ActivityRecord.java:6564)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished(ActivityRecord.java:7351)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.doAnimationFinished(WindowContainer.java:3216)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.onAnimationFinished(WindowContainer.java:3228)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onAnimationFinished(Unknown Source:2)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$com-android-server-wm-SurfaceAnimator(SurfaceAnimator.java:133)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:8)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$1$com-android-server-wm-SurfaceAnimator(SurfaceAnimator.java:143)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished(Unknown Source:4)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.RemoteAnimationController.onAnimationFinished(RemoteAnimationController.java:273)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.RemoteAnimationController.-$$Nest$monAnimationFinished(Unknown Source:0)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.RemoteAnimationController$FinishedCallback.onAnimationFinished(RemoteAnimationController.java:384)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.view.IRemoteAnimationFinishedCallback$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteAnimationFinishedCallback.java:89)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
03-14 19:49:16.616   572  5238 W WindowManager:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```